# How to Heroku-style app monitoring in Dokku?

Tags: heroku, monitoring, grafana, dokku

I really like Heroku's app monitoring. But I don't have it in my Dokku PaaS. I want to see my apps and plugins CPU, RAM, disk load, network IO, ...

Is there a way that I can easily collect and visualize these stats with Dokku? Is there an out-of-the-box solution for this or I need to manually set up the Grafana and it's integration to each app and plugin?

How you monitor your Dokku apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no straightforward way to do this.

What we're doing in our project is we have a cron job that collects the stats of individual Dokku apps directly from Docker every couple minutes:

```bash
docker stats --no-stream --format "{{.Container}},{{.Name}},{{.CPUPerc}},{{.MemUsage}},{{.MemPerc}},{{.NetIO}},{{.BlockIO}}" > docker-stats.csv
```

And the data from the CSV file is then loaded directly into our custom admin UI (using a JavaScript lib called [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info/)):

[image]

It's hacky but it does the job.